# How to move files with their creation time in a specific range?

Tags: python

I'd like to move files (not copy) base on range of file time modification.
I try to find solution and I found code as below.

```
import os
import shutil
import time
from datetime import datetime

src = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/"
dst = "C:/Users/eldri/OneDrive/Desktop/output"
ext = input("[+] File format: ")  # "txt"
start = input("[+] Date start: ")  # "01/07/2020"
end = input("[+] Date end: ")  # "30/07/2020"


def dateRange(createdDate, startDate, endDate):
    """determines if date is in range"""
    createdDate = datetime.strptime(createdDate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
    startDate = datetime.strptime(startDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    endDate = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%d/%m/%Y')
    return startDate < createdDate < endDate


for filename in os.listdir(src):
    created = time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(src + filename))
    if filename.endswith('.' + ext) and dateRange(created, start, end):
        shutil.copy(src + filename, dst)
        print("[+] File transferred " + filename + created)
    else:
        print("[+] File not transferred " + filename + created)

print("[+] Transfer complete")
```

This code is work when I put specific date modification require but I want to move file base on range of file modification time.

for example : If create modification time 00:00 - 12:00 move file to a folder1
and 13:00 - 24:00 move to folder2 by do not necessary input range of time.

Please supporting if you have any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime.time` instead if you want use time of day. To convert the "Unix" time from `os.path.getmtime()` to a `time` object, I think its easier to first make a `datetime`. I didn't include any input reading since I wasn't sure how you want to deal with it:

```
import datetime
import os

def created_in_range(created, start_hours, end_hours):
    created_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(created).time()
    return datetime.time(hour=start_hours) < created_time < datetime.time(hour=end_hours)

src = "."

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        continue

    created = os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(src, filename))
    if created_in_range(created, 0, 12):
        print("Move to folder_1")
    elif not created_in_range(created, 0, 13):
        print("Move to folder_2")
```

I had to use a `not` keyword for 1300 - 2400 range since the "hour" argument for `time` needs to be in between 0 and 23.

Comment: Thank you very much. This code is work but I have to delete `not` from `if not os.path.isfile(filename):`